# Is there a way of accessing HTML tag attribute in CSS within Shadow-DOM?

Tags: html, css, typescript, shadow-dom, stenciljs

I'm creating a custom component with StencilJS and I have to made some changes of the outline when the user is using the keyboard or the mouse to navigate into the component.

My component is using ShadowDOM and I want to access an HTML tag attribute from the CSS.

The tag's attributes are generated with what-input (https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input) to detect keybord and mouse events.

I've tried using CSS Selectors like `[data-whatintent=keyboard]` and `html[data-whatintent=keyboard]` but it didn't worked.

This is my HTML tag from which I want to access `data-whatintent` attribute:

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" data-whatinput="keyboard" data-whatintent="mouse">

  <my-custom-component></my-custom-component>

</html>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
[data-whatintent=keyboard] *:focus {
  outline: solid 2px #1A79C6;
}
```

I want that my CSS within the ShadowDOM can use the `data-whatintent` attribute's value to set styles on my component so the outline is like I want.

Comment: You can access it from the component easily e.g. `document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('data-whatintent')`, but applying the attribute value to style is a whole other question. What exactly do you need to do with the value? Are there a finite number of possible values that you know in advance?

Comment: Only 2 possible values: keyboard or mouse, but I only want the CSS to have effect when the value is `keyboard`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supersharp's answer is correct, however it's not StencilJS code and also host-context support is flakey (doesn't work in Firefox and probably IE11).

You can 'transfer' the attribute to the host element, and then use the selector from inside the host component style:

TSX:

```
private intent: String;

componentWillLoad() {
    this.intent = document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('data-whatintent');
}

hostData() {
    return {
        'data-whatintent': this.intent
    };
}
```

SCSS:

```
:host([data-whatintent="keyboard"]) *:focus {
    outline: solid 2px #1A79C6;
}
```

If the `data-whatintent` attribute changes dynamically, make it a property of the component, and have the listener function update your component. You can optionally use the property to add/remove classes to the host for styling, although you could also continue to use the attribute selector.

TSX:

```
@Prop({ mutable: true, reflectToAtrr: true }) dataWhatintent: String;

componentWillLoad() {
    this.dataWhatintent = document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('data-whatintent');
}

hostData() {
    return {
        class: { 
            'data-intent-keyboard': this.dataWhatintent === 'keyboard' 
        }
    };
}
```

SCSS:

```
:host(.data-intent-keyboard) *:focus {
    outline: solid 2px #1A79C6;
}
```

Document's keyboard and mouse event handler:

```
function intentHandler(event: Event) {
    const intent = event instanceof KeyboardEvent ? 'keyboard' : 'mouse';
    document.querySelectorAll('my-custom-component').forEach(
        el => el.setAttribute('data-whatintent', intent)
    );
}
```

Comment: With this, `intent` will always have the same value ? The value of `data-whatintent` is update everytime the user move his mouse or press a key.

Comment: If that's the use case, then whatever listener is handling the mouse and keyboard usage should fire an event that the component can listen to and update the "intent" value. One possible approach anyway.

Comment: My CSS didn't update, but my component is re-rendering and `intent` is update correctly...

Comment: I added an example for dynamic updating.

Answer (score 2):

You sould use [:host-context()](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#contextstyling) to apply a CSS style in a Shadow DOM depending on the context where the Custom Element is used.

```js
customElements.define( 'my-custom-component', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
            .innerHTML = `
              <style>
                :host-context( [data-whatinput=keyboard] ) *:focus {
                   outline: solid 2px #1A79C6;
                }
              </style>
              <input value="Hello">`
    }
} )
```

```html
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" data-whatinput="keyboard" data-whatintent="mouse">

  <my-custom-component></my-custom-component>

</html>
```

Comment: It didn't work using Stencil. I didn't have access to `attachShadow()`.

Comment: @vincino but you can define CSS for your component no?